# Filter SQL query based on scalar function result

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I can't seem to use an aliased column name in the `WHERE` clause

This doesn't work

```
SELECT *, [dbo].[myFunc] (X.Prop1) AS Width 
FROM X 
WHERE Width > 0
```

I have to do

```
SELECT *, [dbo].[myFunc] (X.Prop1) AS Width 
FROM X 
WHERE [dbo].[myFunc] (X.Prop1) > 0
```

My concern is that SQL is executing `[dbo].[myFunc] (X.Prop1)` twice.

My questions are:

- Is it executing twice or is SQL Server smart enough?
- Is there a way to use an aliased column in the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try both ways, they have the exact same execution plan, so looks like the query optimizer is smart enough to find out that they are the same query and run it once...
So both ways are OK I assume...

But if want to use the subquery approach and use the alias you can use a something like this:

```
Select * from (
SELECT *, [dbo].[myFunc] (X.Prop1) AS Width FROM X 
) T
WHERE Width > 0
```

Comment: @jpw I think you are right, Just tested it, when the functions are exact same thing, the execution plan is the same too.. updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it is calculated twice or not, but you can avoid this using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT *, Width  
FROM X 
CROSS APPLY (Select [dbo].[myFunc] (X.Prop1)) N(Width)
WHERE Width > 0
```

Look this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/639) that selects the square of values that are greater than 10.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

```
;WITH cteMyData AS
(
   SELECT *, [dbo].[myFunc] (X.Prop1) AS Width 
   FROM X
)
SELECT * FROM cteMyData WHERE Width > 0
```